# Prove if $z=a+bi$ is a root of the polynomial P(z), $\overline{z} =a-bi$ will be a root too.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have a polynomial $P( z) =a_{n} z^{n} +...+a_{1} z+a_{0}$ with real coefficients and I know that $z=a+bi$ is a root of it, but I don't know how to prove that $\overline{z}$ is a root too. Thanks!

Comment: It only applies when all coefficients are real.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that information, but coefficients are reals.

Comment: Can you rely on $P(\bar{z})=\overline{P(z)}$ (if coefficients are real)? Can you prove it?

Comment: I didn't realize that was important information, yes I can prove that $P(\overline{z}) =\overline{P( z)}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prove the statement we will use the following facts:
\begin{align*}
\overline{x+y} &= \overline{x} + \overline{y} \\
\overline{x\cdot y} &= \overline{x}\cdot\overline{y}
\end{align*}
Also recall that for $r \in \mathbb{C}$
\begin{gather*}
r\in\mathbb{R} \iff r = \overline{r}
\end{gather*}
Then
\begin{gather*}
P(\overline{z}) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \overline{z}^i = \sum_{i=0}^n \overline{a_i} \overline{z^i} = \overline{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i z^i} = \overline{P(z)}
\end{gather*}
Recall that $\lambda$ is a root of $P(z) \iff P(\lambda)=0$. But then $P(\overline{\lambda}) = \overline{P(\lambda)}=0$, so $\overline{\lambda}$ is also a root of $P(z)$

Comment: I alredy prove that, but I don't find a way to connect that with this: $P(\overline{z})=P(z)=0, z=a+bi$

Comment: Check out the edit of the post